# Convert a row of cv::Mat to an int

Tags: c++, opencv, freak

I have a matrix of descriptors from FREAK description extraction where each row is a descriptor of 64 elements.

I need to create a `vector <int*>` from this matrix due to the system requirements. I tried this so far:

```
Mat _descriptors;
std::vector<int*> descriptors;
int row;
for (int i=0; i<_descriptors.rows;i++)
{
    row =(int) _descriptors.row(i).data;
    descriptors.push_back( & row );
}
```

Is this correct or is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the values in `descriptors` will point to the variable `row` on the stack with this code.

Looking at the definition of a opencv `Mat`, `row` returns by value:

```
// returns a new matrix header for the specified row
Mat row(int y) const;
```

Accessing the data in `_descriptors` directly and stepping with provided stride member variable `step` should work however:

```
Mat _descriptors;
std::vector<int*> descriptors;
for (int i=0; i<_descriptors.rows;i++)
{
    descriptors.push_back((int*)(_descriptors.data + i * _descriptors.step));
}
```

Comment: Anyway your code won't compile, I changed static_cast<> by this: (int*)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a new object for the vector `descriptors`, you are creating an object with the address of the `row` variable and not it's actual value. To store the value, if it is this what you want, the code should look like this.

```
Mat _descriptors;
std::vector<int> descriptors;
int row;
for (int i=0; i<_descriptors.rows;i++)
{
    row =(int) _descriptors.row(i).data;
    descriptors.push_back( row );
}
```

I also change the `vector<int*> descriptors` to `vector<int> descriptors`.

Comment: Well, this is not what I want, i need a vector<int*> as another funtion requires it, and it is not up to me to change it.

Comment: Ok, so you should use `vector<int*> descriptors` and when creating an object just call `descriptors.push_back( new int(row) );`